# How can I change the last slide opacity to 0 (transparent) if the active slide is the first one?

Tags: jquery, css, frontend, slick.js

I want to make the last slide opacity to 0 when the centered slide is the first one.

[image]

Here is a pen of what I have done so far:

https://codepen.io/Guerreiro-Borghi/pen/NWBRqLa

Any help is welcome!
Thanks!

I tried

```
slickCarousel.on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  const lastSlide = slick.slideCount - 1;
  
  if (currentSlide === lastSlide ) {
    jumpBack();
  }

  if (currentSlide === 0) {
    $('.last-slide').css('opacity') = '0';
    // set last slide opacity to 0
  } else {
    // set opacity to 1
    $('.last-slide').css('opacity') = '1';
  }
});
```

Comment: Or use something like: `if (currentSlide == 0) {
    $('.slick-slide.slick-active').first().css('opacity', '0.3');
  } `

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS;

```css
.slick-slide:has(+ .slick-current) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and change to whatever opacity you want. Note that this solution does not work on older browser as [:has() is a newer CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (Firefox still doesn't support it yet).

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help.
Update to how I managed to fix this:

https://codepen.io/Guerreiro-Borghi/pen/NWBRqLa